# Store function calls and execute them

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I wrote these functions to do mixing of a given list:

```
(defun swap (lst pos1 pos2)
  "Destructively swap values of lst between positions pos1 and pos2"
  (let ((aux (nth pos1 lst)))
    (setf (nth pos1 lst) (nth pos2 lst))
    (setf (nth pos2 lst) aux)) lst)

(defun mix-function ()
  "Create function to mix values, and than revert changes"
  (let ((parameters '()))
    (lambda (lst)
      (let ((len (length lst)))
        (if (null parameters)
            (dotimes (i len)
              (push (list (random len) (random len)) parameters))
          (setf parameters (nreverse parameters)))
        (map nil #'(lambda (x) (apply #'swap (cons lst x))) parameters) lst))))
```

Example call:

```
CG-USER(109): (defparameter fun (mix-function))
FUN
CG-USER(110): (defparameter val '(1 2 3 4 5))
VAL
CG-USER(111): (funcall fun val)
(5 2 1 4 3)
CG-USER(112): (funcall fun val)
(1 2 3 4 5)
```

Is it possible to do this by storing function calls? How would I do that? What i have so far doesn't work well when setf is used after first funcall:

```
(defun mix-function2 ()
  (let ((operations '()))
    (lambda (lst)
      (let ((len (length lst)))
        (if (null operations)
            (dotimes (i len)
              (push `(swap ',lst ,(random len) ,(random len)) operations))
          (setf operations (nreverse operations)))
        (map nil #'eval operations) lst))))

CG-USER(140): (defparameter fun2 (mix-function2))
FUN2
CG-USER(141): val
(1 2 3 4 5)
CG-USER(142): (funcall fun2 val)
(5 2 1 4 3)
CG-USER(143): (setf val '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
(1 2 3 4 5 6)
CG-USER(144): (funcall fun2 val)
(1 2 3 4 5 6)
CG-USER(145): (funcall fun2 val)
(1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

And can it be written without eval?

Comment: What do you mean "storing function calls"?  (update) Oh, You're storing blobs of code and then eval'ing them.  Yes, you could `(push (lambda () (swap ...) operations)` and then `(map nil 'funcall operations)`.

Comment: Also, are you aware that `(if (null operations) (dotimes ...) (setf ...))` does *either* the dotimes or the setf, not both?  The syntax for `if` is `(if condition then [else])`.  You're populating operations the first time, and reversing the second time (once it's non-empty).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Yes, I am aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that are a bit odd with your first attempt.  You return a function that, if **operations** isn't yet populated, will create as many swaps as there are in the list that the function is called with.  But then you can call that function on any list, even if it doesn't have the same length.  If you call it with a long list, and then pass in a shorter list, you'll try to swap places that the list doesn't actually have.  Also, you don't need to write **swap**;  Common Lisp already provides a more general [**rotatef**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_rotate.htm), which accepts arbitrary places, like **nth**.  So, I'd write this as a function that accepts a list and then returns a function whose successive invocations return shuffled versions of that list.  The trick to avoiding the kind of **eval** usage you've shown is to collect **lambda** functions rather than code blobs, and then to **funcall** them.

```
(defun make-shuffler (list)
  (let* ((len (length list))
         (operations (loop repeat len
                          collect (let ((i (random len))
                                        (j (random len)))
                                    (lambda ()
                                      (rotatef (nth i list) (nth j list)))))))
    (lambda () 
      (map nil 'funcall operations)
      list)))
```

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *f* (make-shuffler (list 1 2 3 4 5 6)))
*F*
CL-USER> (funcall *f*)
(4 1 5 2 3 6)
CL-USER> (funcall *f*)
(2 4 3 1 5 6)
CL-USER> (funcall *f*)
(1 2 5 4 3 6)
CL-USER> (funcall *f*)
(4 1 3 2 5 6)
CL-USER> (funcall *f*)
(2 4 5 1 3 6)
CL-USER> (funcall *f*)
(1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

Of course, there are lots of options for creating the list of swap functions, too.  Beware of using capturing **loop** variables, though, because they might not be rebound on each iteration.  (That's why I used the **let** within the **collect** clause.)  But you could also just collect the random indices, and then call a single swapping function.  That might be more memory efficient (but I haven't checked):

```
 (defun make-shuffler (list)
  (let* ((len (length list))
         (index-pairs (loop repeat len
                         collect (list (random len) (random len))))
         (swap (lambda (i j)
                 (rotatef (nth i list) (nth j list)))))
    (lambda ()
      (map nil (lambda (indices)
                 (apply swap indices))
           index-pairs)
      list)))
```

Also, in response to your comment, note that the list returned by the **make-shuffler** function is always the same list, just with its elements in a different order.  That means that you can modify the list between calls to the shuffler function, and you'll see the changes reflected (however that makes sense).  For instance:

```
(let* ((list (list 1 2 3 4 5))
       (f (make-shuffler list)))
  (funcall f)
  (print list)
  (setf (second list) 'x)
  (setf (third list) 'y)
  (print list)
  (funcall f)
  (print list))

; (3 4 2 1 5) ; after first shuffle
; (3 X Y 1 5) ; after setting X and Y, but without shuffling
; (Y 1 X 3 5) ; after another shuffle, X and Y are still in the list
```

Comment: Thank you :), but I didn't mention (sorry), my goal was to create a function which could be used like this: `(funcall x-mixer x) ... do something with x ... (funcall x-mixer x)`. That is to mix it, do something with value of x (which could involve setfing but not cahnging length of list) and than revert changes made by mixing. It sounds weird, I know, but that's what i meant to do.

Comment: OK, but what happens if you do (funcall x-mixer list-with-10-elements) and then (funcall x-mixer list-with-2-elements).  The second will try to swap elements that might be at indexes higher than 0 and 1.  Note that the version that I provided returns *the same list* each time.  If you do something in between, and make another call, you'll see the changes from what you did. I'll just added an example.

Comment: For example if I change the line `(setf (second list) 'x)` from your added code to `(setf list (cons 'x (cdr list)))`, it won't work ... Do you know why?

Comment: Yes.  The closure can only capture what's available to it when it's created.  What's available to it when it's created is the lexical variable `list` within the make-shuffler function.  If you want to destructively modify the list, though, you can, but you'll need to modify the actual underlying structure.  E.g., if you want to push a new value, you'd need to do something like `(push (first list) (rest list)) (setf (first list) 'x)`.